# Excel VBA script powered by supercomputers?

Tags: vba, hpc, supercomputers

Is there a software/service/hardware available to run **simple VBA scripts** on a supercomputer (a **remote cluster of CPUs**)?
I mean without installing the complex official HPC Excel extensions and spending time learning it...

I mean something as **easy to use** as this:

```
Sub test()
   SupercomputerLib.upload(ThisWorkbook)
   ArrayOfResults = SupercomputerLib.Execute("complexFunc(100)", _
                                             "complexFunc(200)", _
                                             "complexFunc(300)", _
                                             "complexFunc(400)", _
                                             "complexFunc(500)", _
                                             "complexFunc(600)", _
                                             "complexFunc(700)", _
                                             "complexFunc(800)", _
                                             "complexFunc(900)", _
                                             "complexFunc(1000)")
   'ArrayResult will be generated in 1 day of parallel calculus
End sub

Function complexFunc(someNumber as integer) as long
   *complex calculus that takes 1 day on a single CPU*
End Function
```

Comment: Why would someone want to do that? Sort of like flying paper airplanes in wind tunnels. In any event -- it is off-topic to ask to recommends/find software libraries.

Comment: I'm developing an algorithm for automatic trading and want to test my algorithm on big historical data (1 million of rows) trying many different variations (values of variables) for finding the most performing one.

I already have the VBA functions, I just need to execute many times (the more, the better) changing their argument values, like in my simplified example.

Comment: @6diegodiego9 That is reasonable enough, but VBA itself is a single-threaded interpreted language from the late 1990s. It is wonderful for adding functionality to spreadsheets, but doesn't really scale well. You could treat your VBA code as a protototype but then rewrite it in a compiled language. VBA => VB.Net is typically a straightforward (but not quite mechanical) translation. With VB.Net Excel InterOp, the resulting code could still interact with Excel smoothly.

Comment: @John the Microsoft HPC Pack that is the official Microsoft software for using Excel/VBA powered by supercomputers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/high-performance-computing/hpcpack-excel-vba   but it requires the ability to install new apps on my PC (which I don't have) and time to learn it.  I don't think that I need all that complexity for my task...

Comment: If it is for work -- why not talk to your manager? Unless he/she is a Dilbert-style pointy-haired boss, why wouldn't they want their employees using tools which are adequate for the job? Also, the learning curve might not be as large as you fear. At a quick glance of the documentation, it doesn't seem that bad. The tutorial that goes with it seems easy enough to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Af far as I know, there's no such a software/service available